# HTAccess 301 Redirect Plus Query String Changed To A Path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

http://www.domain.com/old-name-here?manufacturer=445 should display as:

http://www.domain.com/new-name-here/brand-name

If I enter the following htaccess code:

Redirect 301 /old-name-here?manufacturer=445 /new-name-here/brand-name-here

It does redirect properly via 301, but it keeps the query string on the end and only redirects the 1st folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect` directive cannot match QUERY_STRING. You should use `mod_rewrite` rules.

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)manufacturer=45(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^old-name-here/?$ /new-name-here/brand-name-here? [NC,L,R=301]
```

`?` in the end will strip any existing query string from target URI.

Comment: Hi Anubhava! It is working but has one error. When I enter "RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^manufacturer=445 [NC]
RewriteRule ^mens/?$ $0/7-for-all-mankind? [R=301,L,R]" I get this URL: domain.com/mens//7-for-all-mankind  (double slash instead of one)

Comment: Use this one: `RewriteRule ^(mens)/?$ $1/7-for-all-mankind? [R=301,L,R]` with the same `RewriteCond`

Comment: Hello again - can you tell me what the $1/7 means where you had $0/7 before? I am trying to understand what the ?$ and $1 means. The question mark at the end of the rule means no query string? I'm not quite sure what each part means, but it does appear to be working.

Comment: For a given URI `/mens/?manufacturer=445`,  `$1` represents the matched group #1 in regex `^(mens)/?$` which is equal to `mens` whereas `$0` represents whole URI hence that is equal to `/mens/` and causes double slash.

Comment: Yes as I wrote in my answer: `? in the end will strip any existing query string from target URI.`